# jquery, simplemodal with a tooltip?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using http://dev.mariusilie.net/content/simple-tooltip-jquery-plugin for my tooltip and simple modal for a modal window. I've got a link in the modal window and when I put my mouse over it, the tooltip is there, but it's beneath the modal window. I think it has to do with "z-index". I looked and I think the modal window is at 1000. I've set the #simpleTooltip property in the css with various z-index values, with no luck. It always appears beneath the modal window.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what browser are you having this issue? Are you actually using SimpleModal, or some other modal library?

Setting the z-index on the tooltip should work, or you can set the z-index for SimpleModal to a lower value:

```
$(element).modal({zIndex:10});
```

The value should be at least 5 below the tooltip value.

Comment: Perfect. I was playing with the modal css; didn't realize it was one of the options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you modal uses an iframe behind it? if so then your z-index can never win the war as iframe always stays on top.

In that case consider using a modal that does not use an iframe or put your tooltip on top of an iframe too but i do not recommend that later.